# The mp4box.exe is not called by web service after publish

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I have a web service written in C# that uses 2 external applications for video conversion (ffmpeg.exe and MP4Box.exe).

The problem is that when I run web service code, both applications are called for conversion as I expected, but when I publish the code, the second application is never called.

The code that calls the .exe app:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "\\MP4Box\\MP4Box.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-inter 500 " + finalMediaPath;                      
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
```

And I am using IIS in order to publish web service. I suppose that there is nothing to do in IIS, as the first app works fine.

Comment: Are those applications console applications? Second, can you please post the code where to execute the process that will start? third, is there an exception thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue. In case this will be usefull for someone else.

In my MP4Box call i added -tmp param. Probably published web service didn't have access to default temp path used my windows.